# How to chain Objects in C#

Tags: c#, object, reference

I have got 4 questions:

1. How is it possible that I am able to print Console.WriteLine(list.head.Next.Next.Data).
   From the AddHead(), the new object will save over the previous object n.Next?
2. I created a custom class to try and understand if I the above example is only List specific.
   So, how is it possible that I can Console.WriteLine(cc.head.Next.Next.Next.Data) ?
3. How do I post code inside a box for the forum, this is my first post, please forgive me.

Thank you !

```
using System;

namespace GenericInterfaces
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            //Declare and instantiate a new generic SortedList class.
            //Person is the type argument.
            SortedList<Person> list = new SortedList<Person>();

            //Create name and age values to initialize Person objects.
            string[] names = new string[]
            {
            "Franscoise",
            "Bill",
            "Li",
            "Sandra",
            "Gunnar",
            "Alok",
            "Hiroyuki",
            "Maria",
            "Alessandro",
            "Raul"
            };

            int[] ages = new int[] { 45, 19, 28, 23, 18, 9, 108, 72, 30, 35 };

            //Populate the list with new Node Objects
            for (int x = 0; x < 10; x++)
            {
                //ages[x] is integer
                list.AddHead(new Person(names[x],ages[x]));
            }

            //Print out unsorted list.
            foreach (var p in list)
            {
                System.Console.Write(p.ToString() + " ");
                Console.WriteLine("Unsorted Data");
                Console.WriteLine(list.head.Data);
                Console.WriteLine(list.head.Next.Data);
                Console.WriteLine(list.head.Next.Next.Data);
                Console.WriteLine(list.head.Next.Next.Next.Data);

            }
            System.Console.WriteLine("Done with unsorted list");


            Console.WriteLine("My Custom Class Experiment");
            MyCustomClass cc = new MyCustomClass();
            for (int i = 0; i < ages.Length; i++)
            {
                cc.AddHead(ages[i]);
            }
            Console.WriteLine("Added ages to custom class");
            Console.WriteLine(cc.head.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(cc.head.Next.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(cc.head.Next.Next.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(cc.head.Next.Next.Next.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(cc.head.Next.Next.Next.Next.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(cc.n.Data);
            Console.WriteLine(cc.n.Next.Data);

        }
    }
    //Type parameter T in angle brackets.
    public class GenericList<T> : System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable<T>
    {
        public Node head;
        public Node current = null;

        // Nested class is also generic on T
        public class Node
        {
            public Node Next { get; set; } = null;
            public T Data { get; set; }

            public Node(T t)  //T used in non-generic constructor
            {
                Data = t;
            }
        }

        public GenericList()  //constructor
        {
            head = null;
        }

        public void AddHead(T t)  //T as method parameter type
        {
            Node n = new Node(t);
            n.Next = head;
            head = n;
        }

        // Implementation of the iterator
        public System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerator<T> GetEnumerator()
        {
            Node current = head;
            while (current != null)
            {
                yield return current.Data;
                current = current.Next;
            }
        }

        // IEnumerable<T> inherits from IEnumerable, therefore this class 
        // must implement both the generic and non-generic versions of 
        // GetEnumerator. In most cases, the non-generic method can 
        // simply call the generic method.
        System.Collections.IEnumerator System.Collections.IEnumerable.GetEnumerator()
        {
            return GetEnumerator();
        }
    }
    public class MyCustomClass
    {
        public Mode head;
        public Mode current = null;
        public Mode n;

        // Nested class is also generic on T
        public class Mode
        {
            //public Mode Next { get; set; } = null;
            public Mode Next;
            public int Data { get; set; }

            public Mode(int t)  //T used in non-generic constructor
            {
                Data = t;
            }
        }

        public void AddHead(int t)  //T as method parameter type
        {
            n = new Mode(t);
            n.Next = head;
            head = n;
        }
    }
```

Comment: I formatted the code. If you like you can compare the two versions by clicking at the "edited" link below your post. (Code is marked by indenting everything by 4 spaces. Marking the code and clicking the `{}`symbol on top does that for you.)

Comment: Hi Peter A. Schneider, thank you for your comment, will give it a try in future !

Answer (score 1):

> the new object will save over the previous object n.Next?

In a LinkedList, the Next property of a list node doesn’t save or manipulate anything about the list, it just returns the Next item that the node is pointing to. The item returned is also a Node, that has its own Next, that points to yet another item in the list. If you repeatedly call Next then you simply travel along the list

Think of it as trying to find your child. You know he went to john’s house. You go to john’s house but are told “they went to paul’s house”, so you go to paul’s house and are told “they went to Sarah’s house”, so you go to Sarah’s house...

At each step you’re being sent to the Next house, but you’re not demolishing anyone’s house. You maintain a memory of where you are in the list of houses. If you went back to johns house and started over (the list head) you would travel the same route again

If you were to make a new variable pointing to the head of the list, and then repeatedly reassign it to Next, then you’re always changing the Node your temp variable is pointing to, but the list nodes themselves always stay pointing to each other too, and you don’t disturb their relationship:

```
var tempNode = list.Node; //tempNode is you, you’re at john’s house now
tempNode = tempNode.Next; //now you’re at paul’s house
tempNode = tempNode.Next; //now you’re at sarah’s
```

At no time did you disturb any of the existing nodes. What if, when you got to Paul’s house you said to Paul’s dad “if my wife comes asking, tell her my son went to Jane’s house” - this changes where Paul’s dad will point the next person to:

var tempNode = list.Node; //tempNode is you, you’re at john’s house now
    tempNode = tempNode.Next; //now you’re at paul’s house
    tempNode.Next = new Node(“Jane’s house”);

Now we have actually manipulated the list and changed where the Next of the second node is pointing to

> how does AddHead work?

It takes the data you pass in and makes a new Node out of it, then makes the new node's Next point to the existing list head and makes the existing list head point to the new node instead. This effectively makes the list grow  backwards by adding a new head all the time. If you wanted the houses to be visited in order of John, Paul, Sarah you'd have to add them in order of `AddHead(Sarah), AddHead(Paul), AddHead(John)`

The list growth looks like:

```
head->nothing 

head->Sarah

head->Paul->Sarah

head->John->Paul->Sarah
```

I simplified the look of this, to hide Nodes and Next. Every arrow  `->` represents Next, every name is the Data inside a Node

> how do I post code

Put 3 back ticks on their own line, before and after the code block. Or prefix every line in the code with 4 or more spaces

> how should I name the question

That’s really for you to decide, as it helps us understand how you think as does the question body

Comment: Nice metaphor! You could make that a paper chase or scavenger hunt, having a box labeled "next" in each house which may be empty (is null in C#) or contain a reference (i.e, an address ;-) ) of the next house.

Comment: Hi Caius Jard, I still have some difficulty understanding. Here are my thoughts. Everytime the AddHead() is called, a new Node() or Mode object will be created. And, next which is a property of the object will be assigned the previous object.

This is where i get confused. Are we creating a single object with AddHead() and assigning the Next Property. Or are we creating a new Object everytime we invoke the AddHead().

And, does this explanation works for both CustomClass and GenericList<T> ?

Comment: In other words, following your story. When, I invoke the AddHead() the first time, I am creating John house with the property Next which is paul house. the second time i invoke the AddHead(), I am creating Paul House with the property Next which is Sarah house. So if I call Next.Next i am actually calling, Paul.SarahHouse?

Comment: Thank you very much Caius Jard for your detailed explanation! Appreciate it!

Comment: No problems. I forgot to add that this Next.Next.Next isn't really any magic, it's just objects referring to other objects. Suppose if we change things around so it's you, in your House, in your Street, in your City, in your Country then if I have a reference to you I can get to your country with `youPerson.House.Street.City.Country` - it's just with a list they're all the same kind of object that refer to each other so it's always the same name to access the next referenced object